# Installing SSDT hook on Windows 7 32-bit VM returns system error 2

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, rootkit

I use the following code to create a driver that hooks Win7-32bit SSDT table. It is taken straight from Greg & Jamie's book.
Please note that I don't even call the hooking code from main:

main.c
http://pastebin.com/Ck8FSVbv

SSDT_Hook.h
http://pastebin.com/y1ssD1ni

When I try to load it, sc.exe returns error 2.

But I can't figure out why. Couldn't find answers is similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that system cannot find your driver file. You probably specified bad full path when installing the service. Look to the service registry key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<your_service_name>`

for the `ImagePath` value. This value must contain full path to your driver file, either relative to the system root (usually `C:\Windows`), or "totally" absolute – starting with the `\??\X:` prefix (`X` is the drive letter, `\??\` makes the path absolute from the Object Manager point of view).

I assume you grabbed the code from the Rootkits: Subverting the Windows Kernel book. It's a great book, howerver, keep in mind the following:

1) it is kinda old and many of its codes do not work on multiprocessor machines,

2) it is a hacker book which means it does not tell you how to do things nicely, it just tells you how to make a code working somewhat. A code based on it may work but may be full of errors if you lack knowledge about Windows driver development.

That does not mean it is a bad book. It just is not a guide how you should write Windows drivers.

Comment: Actually, when in file SSDT_Hook.h I mark lines 141, 142, 148, 150 as comments, the driver loads fine..

Comment: WHich lines did you exactly marked as comments? Maybe, the driver uses a routine that is not exported by the kernel on Windows 7.

Comment: 141. m_UserTime.QuadPart += curr->UserTime.QuadPart;
142. m_KernelTime.QuadPart += curr->KernelTime.QuadPart; 148. prev->NextEntryDelta += curr->NextEntryDelta; 151.prev->NextEntryDelta = 0;